# cascading drop-down not populating in IE 9 (Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, internet-explorer

I created a cascading drop-down in Codeigniter, but the second drop-down is not populating in IE 9 and IE 8. Here's the relevant controller:

```
public function buildDropEquipment($class)
    // This builds the dropdown field for newly added equipment
    {
         //set selected class id from POST
        $class = $this->input->post('class',TRUE);
        error_log("class variable: ".$class." \n", 3, "/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log");


        //run the query for the cities we specified earlier
        $this->load->model('admin/MEquipment');
        $equipmentData['equipmentDrop']=$this->MEquipment->getEquipmentByClass($class);

       $output = null;

        foreach ($equipmentData['equipmentDrop']->result() as $row)
        {
            //here we build a dropdown item line for each query result
            $output .= "<option value='".$row->type."'>".$row->type."</option>";
        }

        echo  $output;
    }
```

Here's the relevant bit from my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() { 


                $("#class").change(function(){
                     /*dropdown post */
                    $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?/admin/buildDropEquipment",    
                    data: {class: $(this).val()},
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(data){

                        $("#type").html(data);
                    }                  
                    });  
                });
            });       
        </script>      
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--machine class dropdown-->
        <?php $classDrop = array('none' => 'Select One') + $classDrop; ?>
        <dl>
        <dt><strong><?php echo form_label('Equipment Class', 'class');?></strong></dt>
        <dd>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('class', $classDrop,'','class="required" id="class"');  ?>
        </dd>
        </dl>

        <!--equipment type dropdown-->
        <dl>
        <dt><strong><?php echo form_label('Equipment Type', 'type');?></strong></dt>
        <dd>
        <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="">Select Equipment Class Above</option>
        </select>
        </dd>
        </dl>
```

Can anyone tell me why it might not be working correctly in IE 9 and 8?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your Javascript console?

Comment: Nope. No errors in the console.

Comment: If it's helpful, I adopted this code from the following tutorial: http://wecamefrommars.tumblr.com/post/48854835407/codeigniter-how-to-make-mysql-cascade-dropdowns

Comment: Try to Quote your `class` like this `data:{'class': $(this).val()},`

Answer (score 0):

Because 'class' is a reserved keyword in javascript, you should change it to class_name :

```
data: {class_name: $(this).val()},
```

Comment: I changed it (and the corresponding form input field values) to machine_class. However, it it still not working properly in IE 8 or 9.

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me. maybe it's just the cache. Try CTRL+F5

Comment: It's still not working for me -- I'm having to test it using Browserstack (which lets you do live testing of a site on various browsers)...and it loads up a new virtual machine for each new test. So, I don't think it's the cache. I'm at a loss.

Comment: There is something else in your php code, the buildDropEquipment() function have a required parameter ($class), but in your js code there is no sign of it, I know you are using a POST method so maybe you should fix this problem first, and try to return a hardcoded value just for the test. public function buildDropEquipment() { echo 'SUCCESS'; die;  }

Comment: I did try your code using BrowserStack, and it works just fine for me. If you can share some screenshots or even your screen with me, it will be easier for debugging

Comment: Actually, Simo, you were right! I don't know why I had that parameter in there -- I think I misunderstood how that machine class value was getting passed to that function. Once I removed that parameter from that function, it worked fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed on IE 9 by changing the settings of IE 9 to compatible mode.
(IE 9 ->Settings -> F12  Developer Tools -> Browse Mode -> Then Select IE 9 Compatibility). It seems to work for our ADF Apps with cascaded dropdowns

Comment: You want to ask users who can't be bothered to keep their browser up to date to hack it just for your application?